# Unable to gather data using PySpark connection with Hive

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently trying to run queries via PySpark. All went well with the connection and accessing the database. Unfortunately, when I run a query; the only output that is displayed are the column names followed by `None`.

I read through the documentation but could not find any answers. Posted Below is how I accessed the Database.

```
try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark import SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    print ("Successfully imported Spark Modules")
except ImportError as e:
    print ("Can not import Spark Modules", e)
    sys.exit(1)


sc = SparkContext('local', 'pyspark')
sqlctx = SQLContext(sc)


df = sqlctx.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:hive2://.....").option("dbtable", "(SELECT * FROM dtable LIMIT 10) df").load()


print df.show()
```

The output of `df.show()` is just the column names. When I run the same query using `Pyhive` there is data that is populated, so I assumed it has to do something with the way I am trying to load the data table using PySpark.

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve this ? We are facing the same problem